# Cannot install R in RHEL 8.5 using a Dockerfile script

Tags: r, dockerfile, rstudio

I can install R and RStudio with no problem from the RHEL 8.5 CLI.

However, when I try to automate the installation process using a Dockerfile following the instructions at https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r-source/, I get the following error when trying to pass the value defined in my "export R_VERSION=4.0.2" instruction:

```
[ 6/11] **RUN yum install -y R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck**:
#9 0.957 Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:04 ago on Fri Mar 25 19:22:44 2022.
#9 1.066 Can not load RPM file: R--1-1.x86_64.rpm.
#9 1.071 Could not open: R--1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

```
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install -y R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck]: exit code: 1
```

Help is appreciated.

```
sh-4.4# **yum install -y R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck**
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:02 ago on Fri Mar 25 15:56:49 2022.
Dependencies resolved.
=============================================================================================================================================================== Package                                     Architecture               Version                                      Repository                           Size
===============================================================================================================================================================Installing:
R-4.0.2                                     x86_64                     1-1                                          @commandline                         58 M
Upgrading:
glibc                                       x86_64                     2.28-164.el8_5.3                             ubi-8-baseos                        3.6 M
glibc-common                                x86_64                     2.28-164.el8_5.3                             ubi-8-baseos                        1.3 M
glibc-minimal-langpack                      x86_64                     2.28-164.el8_5.3                             ubi-8-baseos                         58 k
......
...........
.............
..................

**Complete!**
sh-4.4# r
sh: r: command not found
sh-4.4# /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R --version
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

Comment: Can you try to use `ENV R_VERSION=4.0.2` instead of "export R_VERSION=4.0.2" ?

Comment: I replaced "RUN export R_VERSION=4.0.2" with "ENV R_VERSION=4.0.2" in the Dockerfile and I got this error: => ERROR [ 5/10] RUN yum install -y R-4.0.2-1-1.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck

Comment: It cannot load the RPM package:  #8 10.98 Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeRea  24 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
#8 11.39 Can not load RPM file: R-4.0.2-1-1.x86_64.rpm.
#8 11.39 Could not open: R-4.0.2-1-1.x86_64.rpm6_64
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install -y R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck]: exit code: 1
   2/2

Comment: I also tried both export and install command in one Dockerfile layer: RUN export R_VERSION=4.0.2 && yum install -y R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck  and same error above

Comment: Oguzhan Aygun: Problem solved. Your suggestion to use the ENV Dockerfile instruction solved the problem. The problem was that I was missing two characters in the prior *** curl *** instructions.  Thank you.